# What is a "monetary non-event" for a corporation?

Tags: equities, finance

Not "non-monetary event" because that would make too much sense. I've never really seen this kind of a question before, but someone asked me that question because they didn't know what it meant either, it has something to do with stocks after a split as far as I can gather, but no online source seems to use that phrase.

Comment: "It will be a a monetary non-event", just means it is not going to make any difference from an economic (dollars and cents) point of view. The dictionary definition of non-event is "a disappointing or insignificant event or occasion, especially one that was expected or intended to be exciting or interesting". In other words "we expected something, nothing much happened".

Comment: See a dictionary definition doesn't necessarily carry the context in this specific field. For instance you can say something is derivative of something else, but that has a very different meaning in literary terms from mathematical terms. If what you're saying is true you should be able to reference a credible source that says "this is a monetary non-event."

Comment: Quote "For all intents and purposes, stock splits don't affect shareholders. Actually, they're kind of a non-event … at least as far as you're concerned."  http://www.fool.com/answers/faq/stock-splits/

Answer (score -3):

[image]

The Boxes I made are monetary even stuff. This is basically what their dealing with.

Comment: Can you please clarify. As is the answer is quite unclear.